# If the `li` element is a flexbox, then the bullet will not show?

Tags: css, flexbox

If we have an unordered list, the default is that there are bullets:

```html
<ul>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>world</li>
</ul>
```

However, if we make it `display: flex`, the bullet doesn't show any more:

```css
li { display: flex }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>world</li>
</ul>
```

Is there such a rule in CSS because it might be natural still to show the bullet but let

```css
ul { list-style-type: none; }
```

to control whether to show the bullets.

Comment: the default display is `list-item` if you change it then it's not more a list item (it happen with all the value `inline`; `inline-block`, etc)

Comment: I thought CSS only affects its look, not the "nature" of the element?

Comment: the nature of the element is defined by CSS (the default display come from the user agent CSS)

Comment: If you set the `li` to display as flex-item, you're removing the possibility to set `list-style-type` as it's no longer a `list-item` which is default for `li`.

Comment: ok, I get it... the bullet comes from the CSS property that it is `displayed: list-item` (and that the parents did not disable it)

Comment: @TemaniAfif - No, HTML defines the nature (that is, semantic meaning) of an element. CSS only affects its presentation. But nonopolarity - that's what's happening when you do `display: flex`. You're changing the presentation of the list item from `display: list-item` to `display: flex`, so it doesn't have a bullet anymore (since that's something displayed for list items).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you see the *nature* as semantic but I see it as presentation. I was not refering to the semantic, I was refering to the default behavior that is defined with the user agent CSS as per the specification: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#rendering

Comment: @T.J.Crowder same rendring using different elements: https://jsfiddle.net/Lfkz8yx0/ (I applied the same default CSS to get the same *nature* / *result* / *presentation* with no semantic)

Comment: @TemaniAfif - I would never think of the *"nature"* of an element being its presentation. That's just not a usage of that word that makes sense to me. See [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nature) (it's sense 3) and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nature) (also sense 3). But if you meant presentation, then that's fine, we can just agree to disagree on "nature." :-)

Comment: @TemaniAfif yeah, just like a rabbit, the nature of it is that it is a rabbit, but if somebody cannot see, and can only touch, then the perception (or how it is presented to him) is that it is furry... the nature is still a rabbit. But if a point on a number line is at a certain place, we can call it 1 or -1 and it is still the same point. But why when we call it 1, then thePoint² = thePoint but if we call it -1, then thePoint² = -thePoint... this I am not so sure

Comment: in other words. The bullet doesn't come from the fact that the element is `li` but from the fact that it has `list-item` as default value of his display property defined with CSS. This apply to all the elements. A `div` is a block element not because it's a `div` but because of its display

Comment: Let's get to the broader issue: Why are you trying to make a list item into a flex container?  Whatever your reason, nest a div inside the `li` and make that the flex container.

Comment: Wow. JavaScript royalty visiting us here in CSS. An honor @T.J.Crowder. Your answers have gotten me through quite a number of difficult situations. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are right. With dislay:flex you are telling to ul that it's not display:list anymore. If you want bullets to be displayed with flex use pseudo element:

```
ul li:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -7px; /* half bullet height */
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    background: #000;
}
```

Comment: An easier option might be to just add a nested div/span element inside the `<li>` tags that you style with flex

Comment: @kano nested div/span is another option, you are right. But it requires extra html which will significantly increase DOM size in case if there are many lists...